# Sequelize class method works on one model but not the other

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

So i'm building the search functionality for an e-commerce platform. I decided to write class methods 
[that search for a query match in the category model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xR6g.png) as well as the
[product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW3Vw.png). This is what my express [route looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdIYP.png)  . when i run and try to search in this configuration i get a 500 error.

[with this stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw0U2.png). The weirdness comes in when i comment out the category  [look up like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw7T1.png). Then the search functionality works just fine but it only gets me data from the product model. If i comment out the product model, the category class method still doesn't work. i tried console.logging the result of class.search method and i get undefined. My hunch is that the eager loading isn't working somehow...

The Route

```html
const router = require('express').Router()
const { Category, Product } = require('../db/models')
const checkAccess = require('./checkAccess')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
module.exports = router

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const productResult = await Product.search(req.query.search)
    const categoryResult = [] //await Category.search(req.query.search)
    if (![...productResult, ...categoryResult].length) {
      res.json([])
    } else if (productResult.length && categoryResult.length) {
      const foundProducts = [...productResult, ...categoryResult[0].products]
      const foundProductsNoDuplicates = []
      const setOfUniqueIds = new Set()
      foundProducts.forEach(product => {
        if (!setOfUniqueIds.has(product.id)) {
          setOfUniqueIds.add(product.id)
          foundProductsNoDuplicates.push(product)
        }
      })
      res.json(foundProductsNoDuplicates)
    } else if (productResult.length) {
      res.json([...productResult])
    } else {
      res.json([...categoryResult[0].products])
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

The Models

```html
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')
const Category = require('./category')

const Product = db.define('product', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  inventory: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  },
  price: {
    type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
    allowNull: false
  },
  imgUrl: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: '../../images/default-product.jpg'
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  status: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM('inStock', 'outOfStock', 'unavailable')
  }
}, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: product => {
        if (product.imgUrl === '') {
          product.imgUrl = '../../images/default-product.jpg'
        }
      }
    }
  })


Product.search = async function (query) {
  const result = await this.findAll({
    where: {
      name: {
        [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%'
      },
      status: 'inStock',
    },
    include: [{ model: Category }]
  })
  return result
}

module.exports = Product
```

```html
'use strict'

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')
const Product = require('./product')

const Category = db.define('category', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  }
})


Category.search = function (query) {
  return this.findAll({
    where: {
      name: {
        [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: '%' + query + '%'
      },
    },
    include: [Product],
  })
}

module.exports = Category
```

Comment: paste your code here and format it.

Comment: can you remove both includes and try again ? see if it works there, to me in your category include is wrong, is it many to many relationship ? if it is then you need include: [{model: Product}] if it is 1 product to many category then you don't need this include.

Comment: it is a many to many

Comment: so update category include to to [{model: Product}] see if you get pass the getTableName error ? it should give you new error saying product is not associated with category.